# Resampling daily to monthly with 'month-end minus t days' offset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have daily timeseries data in a pandas dataframe.  I need to resample this to monthly using different offsets from a standard month-end frequency.

```
dates = pd.date_range('2016-09-01', '2017-01-10')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[x for x in range(len(dates))],index=dates,columns=['MyData'])
```

I can get to a monthly series with month end frequency:

```
df_monthly = df.resample('M').last()

df_monthly
Out[78]: 
            MyData
2016-09-30      29
2016-10-31      60
2016-11-30      90
2016-12-31     121
2017-01-31     131
```

If Month End = 'M', I would like to have similar monthly slices for 
'M-15', ...'M-2', 'M-1', 'M', 'M+1', M+2', ...'M+15'.
Ultimately I plan to combine these into a single dataframe with column names 'M+T'.

Is there an easy way to do this within pd.DataFrame.resample() or pd.DataFrame.asfreq()?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. You want something like mid-month slices? For example `M-2` is the previous two months or 2 days ago?

Comment: All the output data is 1M frequency slice.
One series will all be end-of month. 
Another series would be 1st of each month (MyData=[30,61,91,122]).  
The next series would be 2nd of each month (MyData=[31,62,92,123]).
I also would like series' for end-of-month minus 1 day (MyData=[28,59,89,120,130], index=2016-09-29, 2016-10-30 etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as per the several ways you asked here is how it is done.

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('2016-09-01', '2017-01-10')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[x for x in range(len(dates))],index=dates,columns=['MyData'])

df_monthly_m1 = df.shift(-1).resample('M').last()
df_monthly_m1

            MyData
2016-09-30    30.0
2016-10-31    61.0
2016-11-30    91.0
2016-12-31   122.0
2017-01-31   131.0

df_monthly_p1 = df.shift(1).resample('M').last()
df_monthly_p1

            MyData
2016-09-30    28.0
2016-10-31    59.0
2016-11-30    89.0
2016-12-31   120.0
2017-01-31   130.0
```

Comment: So simple, thank you!  For what I am looking for the labels would be the other way around: df_monthly_p1 refers to data from the first of each month and involves a shift of -1